# ImportError: DLL load failed pyinstaller

Tags: dll, load, importerror, pyinstaller

I create .exe file wiht pyinstaller and when I try to start it such error occured:

> C:\pyinstaller-develop>C:\pyinstaller-develop\RichardINC_aws\dist\RichardINC_aws.exe
>        Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "", line 8, in 
>       File "C:\pyinstaller-develop\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",line
>   3
>       64, in load_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pillow-3.0.0-py2.7-win32.egg\PIL\Image.py"
>       ,line 66, in 
>       File "C:\pyinstaller-develop\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 364, in load_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pillow-3.0.0-py2.7-win32.egg\PIL_imaging.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pillow-3.0.0-py2.7-win32.egg\PIL_imaging.py",
>   line 6, in **bootstrap**
>       ImportError: DLL load failed: ═х эрщфхэ єърчрээ√щ ьюфєы№.
>       RichardINC_aws returned -1

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this thread on Github](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1376) involving what seems to be a pyinstaller developer could help. I'm having a similar problem with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Python 3.5.1 for Windows but not with pyinstaller for python 3.4.2 in Debian (although the latter creates standalones that won't run in my 64-bit Windows but run fine in Linux).